# The integration with respect to Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let function $C$ denotes [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) in $(0,1)$. Let $C_t$ denote the function such that 
$$
C_t(x):=
\begin{cases}
C(x)&\text{ if }t\leq C(x)\leq 1-t\\
t&\text{ if } C(x)<t\\
1-t&\text{ if } C(x)>1-t
\end{cases}
$$
Define $P(t):=\|C_t(x)-x\|^2_{L^2(0,1)}$ for $0\leq t\leq 1/2$. Then we have $P(t)$ is a continuous increasing function.

My question: would it possible to show that $P'(t)$, the derivative of $P(t)$ with respect to $t$, is well defined a.e., and increasing too?